# Twitter Bootstrap not functioning properly for Asp.Net MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting a new project with asp.net mvc4 internet application.

First thing I did was install a package called `Twitter Bootstrap for Asp.Net MVC 4 Sample` via nuGet.

This installed other two packages `Bootstrap` and `Twitter Bootstrap for Asp.Net MVC 4`.

When I run the application,I get this

[image]

I didn't face this problem in previous projects. When I installed twitter bootstrap, things were fine when i built the application.

Can anyone explain or suggest, what might be going wrong?

Edit 1:

I have another project where bootstrap works fine. When I run the two projects in chrome and check the network, file that are loaded for both the projects are same.

Comment: Please check out the `css/js files loaded perfectly?`. See Network tab of chrome built in fiddle tool(`Press F12`) or FireBug for Firefox

Comment: I checked in chrome and the css and js file are loaded correctly, based upon the other project where twitter bootstrap works

Comment: Are you loading in the bootstrap scripts from a CDN?  I know my local host usually has problems loading from external resources without the `http:` or `https:`.  Many CDNs provide scripts with the protocol missing like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js"></script>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file BundleConfig.cs (or a specific BootstrapBundleConfig.cs) in your "App_start" folder of your MVC4 project.

It will have a declaration of something like this:

```
    // It won't look exactly like this.. 
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap/css/style").Include(
        "~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
        "~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css"
        ));
```

Now you must go to your "Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" file (or whatever you base layout is) and add the following line within your head section.

```
<head>
 /// Other stuff in here 

// This renders the boostrap style
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/css/style")

 // include any overrides to bootstrap you have after the library
</head>
```

Comment: still didn't work, i'll post my bundleconfig and layout.cshtml file here